# How to pass an excel filename in an excel formula in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a simple vlookup macro, which gets data from another workbook and performs the vlookup along with autofill

I ask user input for selecting the file from where the vlookup will look up the cells (target file)

Problem:

I can extract the filename from the path, however if i try to pass the variable (excel workbook name) directly in the formula, it doesn't work

Need guidance about the same

My code so far is this:

```
Sub Macro1()
       '
        ' Macro1 Macro
         ' pdf
         '
        ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
        '

     Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
     fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX), *.XLSX", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
     If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
     Workbooks.Open Filename:=fNameAndPath

     Filename = Right(fNameAndPath, Len(fNameAndPath) - InStrRev(fNameAndPath, "\"))
    'MsgBox Mid(filname, 1, InStr(filname, ".") - 1)

     Windows("PDF_Avatar_Geltool.xlsm").Activate
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
     "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[Filename]3G_HW_BDR'!C4:C5,2,0)"
     Windows("3G_Allcells.xlsx").Activate


     Windows("3G_Allcells.xlsx").Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're currently passing in the string "filename" to the formula. You just need to concatenate the variable into the formula.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[" & Filename & "]3G_HW_BDR'!C4:C5,2,0)"
```

Whenever you include a variable in a string, you will need to concatenate this into the string using ampersands.

Answer (score 0):

`Range().Address(External:=True)` return a valid external address that can be used in formula.

```
Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX), *.XLSX", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub

With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fNameAndPath)
    With .Worksheets("3G_HW_BDR")
        Windows("PDF_Avatar_Geltool.xlsm").Activate
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1]," & .Range("C4:C5").Address(Extrenal:=True) & ",2,0)"

    End With
End With

Windows("3G_Allcells.xlsx").Activate
```